# How to debug TypeLoadException without details in F# code?

Tags: f#, typeloadexception

The problem is one of my types, `Expression<'P>` fails to load with `TypeLoadException`. Unfortunately, Visual Studio fails to show any additional information, including its `InnerException`.

In fact, I can't inspect the exception object at all. Locals don't show `$exception`, and manually typing it into Watches window can't find it either. Stack window is also empty.

I have tried fusion log, but that assembly does not even show up there, e.g. log stops seemingly immediately before this type (and assembly) are loaded.

I have also tried creating a C# project, and debugging it instead of directly debugging F# project, but got the same issue.

I am using F# 4.5 preview via VS 2017 15.8.0 Preview 5, but the issue might not be specific to it (the code uses 4.5 stuff a little).

I recently did a huge change to use custom pointers via `byref` that also included a migration of the projects to target .NET Standard 2.0. There's still one dependency on a pre-.NET Standard F# NuGet package.

FSharp.Core-4.5.2 is installed into all relevant projects, except that dependency.

P.S. if somebody from F# Tools team sees this, the code is in https://github.com/Church-of-the-Singularity/GeneticProgramming , tag `repro/TypeLoadException-Expression`

**UPDATE**
It seems to be a compiler bug. I narrowed down the failing example to the following code:

```
[<Struct>] type Ptr<'P, 'T when 'T: struct>(ptr: 'P) = member this.Address = ptr;;
[<Struct>] type MyExpr<'P> = Zero | Reference of reference:Ptr<'P, MyExpr<'P>>;;
```

If you just paste it into F# interactive, you will see my exception. Reproduces in both 4.1 and 4.5. Reported [to GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5450).

Comment: You should be able to find this in the fusion log. That said, I think this pretty much always means that some DLL that your program needs is not available in the folder where you are running it from. Can you make sure that all your references get copied to the folder where the EXE is running from?

Comment: Could also be static constructor of that type, e.g. a `let` binding that is executed when the type is being loaded.

Comment: @CaringDev, the type is a union type. let bindings are not even allowed there AFAIK

Comment: @TomasPetricek, that's my common experience too - either missing, or wrong version of a .DLL. However, in this case all dependencies of the assembly, containing the type seem to be present in the directory.

Comment: @LOST Whoa, nice debugging!

Comment: @LOST It might make sense to post your UPDATE as an answer to your question, so that you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a compiler bug. I narrowed down the failing example to the following code:

```
[<Struct>] type Ptr<'P, 'T when 'T: struct>(ptr: 'P) = member this.Address = ptr;;
[<Struct>] type MyExpr<'P> = Zero | Reference of reference:Ptr<'P, MyExpr<'P>>;;
```

If you just paste it into F# interactive, you will see my exception. Reproduces in both 4.1 and 4.5. Reported [to GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5450).

Workarounds: in 4.1 swapping order for `'P` and `'T` in `Ptr` definition works :-D